# How i can send the jwt token in my get request in react js axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to send the jwt token in the Axios get request to get the data by the logined user. But I am getting a problem with that.

I want to get the posts of the login user...

Comment: can you add code?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do that:

1. Add it in header of request and you can achieve it in header request from Backend:

Example:

> Axios.get(
> 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads',
> { headers: { Authorization:  } }
> )

2. Use Axios HTTP Interceptor to inject JWT Token for each request

```html
Axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    
    config.headers = { 
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${JWT_Token}`,
    }
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    Promise.reject(error)
});
```